# User member of group and permissons

Tags: debian, permissions

I have `user1` which is member of group `www-data`.

```
$ groups user1
> user1 : user1 www-data
```

I am unable to add/delete something under /var/www/test

The `/var/www/test` is owned by www-data

```
$ ls -l /var/www/test
> drwxr-sr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 aug 11 12:02 subtest
```

How to allow `user1` to manage files and directories created by `www-data` ?

---

I already tried to

- Change the primary group of `user1` to `www-data`
- Logout / login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found something cleaner

Adding the web directory in the personnal directory of the user

```
mkdir -p /home/user1/websites/appOfUser1
chown -Rf user1:user1/home/devone/websites
chmod -Rf 770 /home/user1/websites
```

Then adding this line is /etc/fstab (install bindfs before)

```
bindfs#/var/www/application1 /home/user1/websites/appOfUser1 fuse force-user=user1,force-group=user1,create-for-user=www-data,create-for-group=www-data,create-with-perms=0770,chgrp-ignore,chown-ignore,chmod-ignore 0 0
```

And finally mount it!

```
mount /home/user1/websites/appOfUser1
```

- it solves the concurrency problem, as every user in the equation (every developers and the web server) sees the permissions that he requires to operate properly and safely;
- it solves the impermeability problem, as if you need one developer to access a particular application, you have to add a mountpoint in its home directory, but on the contrary, if the you need one developer to not access a particular application, you just have to not add such a mountpoint in it's home directory.
- it solves the stability problem, as developers will never be able to change the file permissions set on the application files, as required by the web server to operate properly and safely.
- best of all, it's simple to understand and to setup !

[Source](http://blog.netgusto.com/solving-web-file-permissions-problem-once-and-for-all/)

Answer (score 1):

**Try Below:**

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/test
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/test
```

**Additionally:**

```
sudo find /var/www/test -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \; 

sudo find /var/www/test -type f -exec chmod ug+rw {} \;
```

I hope you understand significance of above command as they are pretty clear.

Do not forget to Logout/Login.